# postgresql function have syntax error near declare?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to make a function which can generate a name, and return the generated name but for some reason I am getting an syntax error near declare?

```
-- Drop existing entry_name function
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS manufacturer_registration_entry_name( name  text);

-- Create functions
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION manufacturer_registration_entry_name( name  text)
    DECLARE
           entry_name text := null; 
    BEGIN
            entry_name := name;
            return entry_name;
    END;
$manufacturer_registration_entry_name$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Why am i getting this?

Comment: What your function returns?

Comment: it is supposed to return the `entry_name`

Comment: trigger function must return trigger. if you want to return an string it is not trigger functoin

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev don't mind the comment.. it is not a trigger function but just a normal function.

Comment: You are missing the opening "dollar quote" to match your closing one.

Answer (score 2):

All you are missing is `RETURNS TEXT AS $manufacturer_registration_entry_name$` before the `DECLARE` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Please look below working SQL code:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS manufacturer_registration_entry_name( name  text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION manufacturer_registration_entry_name( name  text)
     RETURNS text  -- declare returns type
     LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$
        DECLARE
           entry_name text := null; 
        BEGIN
           entry_name := "name";
           return entry_name;
        END
    $function$
    ;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5eee1647836318c99ecb264876f53619)

Comment: I am getting syntax error at text?

Comment: it completely works. see fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5eee1647836318c99ecb264876f53619

Comment: I want to give entry_name the value of the input variable, and not string name always

Comment: PostgreSQL use double quotes for identifiers, not strings.  Please look the fiddle for working example, returns exact input string  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5eee1647836318c99ecb264876f53619